# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.learnSphere.entities.Comment'

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, forms, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn Spring therefore making small projects,here i am trying to get a simple name and comment from the front end this is my html front-end

```
<h1>add your comment here</h1>
<form method="post" action="/addComment">
    
    <input type="text"  name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <input type="text" name="comment"  placeholder="Enter comment here">
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and i am trying to store it in my MySQL data base using SpringBoot
this is my Entity class for taking the comment

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    int commentid;
    
    String name;
    String comment;
    

    public Comment() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Comment(int commentid, String name, String comment) {
        super();
        this.commentid = commentid;
        this.name = name;
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public int getCommentid() {
        return commentid;
    }

    public void setCommentid(int commentid) {
        this.commentid = commentid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Comment [commentid=" + commentid + ", name=" + name + ", comment=" + comment + "]";
    }
}
```

and this is my controller class

```
@Controller
public class CommentController {
    
    @Autowired
    UsersService uservice;
    
    @PostMapping("/addComment")
    public String addComment(@ModelAttribute Comment comment) {
    
        System.out.println("Received name: " + comment.getName());
        System.out.println("Received comment: " + comment.getComment());
        uservice.addComment(comment);
        return "Comments";
    }
}
```

when i am trying to typein some int type data like "1 " "2" in my html input fields it gets added into my data base fine but when ever i am trying to add some String type data it gives me a error like

"
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.learnSphere.entities.Comment'
"

this is my repository

```
package com.learnSphere.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.learnSphere.entities.Comment;

public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, String> {

}
```

and this is my Service code

```
@Override
    public String addComment(Comment comment) {
        crepo.save(comment);
        return "Saved successfully!!";
```

i tried checking the entities again and again and the html input fields , maybe i am sending the data wrong or maybe the order of my entity class is wrong but nothings wroking

i have tried everything in my knowledge to solve this but i cant find anything . you guys are pros here please solve this one for me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that in repository interface define like that

`public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, Long> { }`

and in Entitiy class do that

`@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) Long commentid;`

Maybe it is the problem because what i know that ID field should be same with your id class type.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your time Elentari , can you tell what's the difference between the generationType.Auto and generationtype.IDENTIYY...and i fixed the problem with my code it turned out that the Problem was in my Entity class where i named my variable comment same as the Class name Comment

Comment: I glad to hear that you solved , here is the difference :

generationType.Auto: Hibernate selects the generation strategy based on the used dialect, generationtype.IDENTIY: Hibernate relies on an auto-incremented database column to generate the primary key 

There is a article about it  :  [link](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-generate-primary-keys/#:~:text=AUTO%3A%20Hibernate%20selects%20the%20generation,table%20to%20simulate%20a%20sequence.)